# How can I the see actual raw request that gets sent

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

In order to see the raw response I use the OnBeforeDeserialization  event but I want to see the raw request because I am getting errors and I want to know exactly what is being sent.
Is there any way to do this without using the restsharp source code and debugging it?
Thank you

Edit 1:
Managed to catch traffic with fiddler:
this is the TextView of the request:

```
assignee=test&milestone=0&state=open&title=test%20issue&body=test%20issue
```

This is the response:

```
{"message":"Problems parsing JSON"}
```

This is how I configure my request:

var request = new RestRequest();

```
    request.Resource = "repos/" + repo_slug + "/issues";
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { cnt = resp.Content; };
    // Convert Issue:
    GitModels.IssuePost toPostIssue = Git2Bit.GitModels.Bit2GitTranslator.translate(bitIssue);

    request.AddParameter("assignee", toPostIssue.assignee, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
    request.AddParameter("milestone", toPostIssue.milestone, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

    request.AddParameter("state", toPostIssue.state, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

    request.AddParameter("body", toPostIssue.body, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Getting issues instead of posting works.:|

Comment: nothing shows up in fiddler.

Comment: how are you configuring your request?  You would have to have the client send the request to fiddler, then have fiddler forward on the request to the server.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: For the sake of unit testing stuff depending on RestSharp, it would be tremendously nice to *not* have to use Fiddler... because it's hard to use that from a unit testing/mocking context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well fiddler did the trick don't know why it didn't work the first time.
As for posting issues on github I had to send my request in JSON format like this:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { cnt = resp.Content; };

GitModels.IssuePost toPostIssue = Git2Bit.GitModels.Bit2GitTranslator.translate(bitIssue);

request.AddBody(toPostIssue);
```

basically I had to set the proper requestformat and add to the body of the request instead of having to add parameters